# How to get title from an image in openCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I was wondering how to get a title from a image in OpenCV.
At the moment I have this:

```
#Load a color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg',0)
```

From here, I'd like to get the title from 'img' by doing something like

```
img.title()
```

but I don't find any method for doing this.
Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What title? Do you mean the filename? You cannot get the filename after reading the image. Instead, store the filename in a variable (e.g. `img_filename = 'lena.jpg'`) and then you can simply `cv2.imread(img_filename, 0)` and continue to use `img_filename` later if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the name of the image, in which case you can store that and refer back to it in the future. There is no way of retriving it from the Mat object as all that stores is the data of the image itself.

instead of:

```
#Load a color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg',0)
```

save the file name first then use that wherever you need it

```
image_filename = 'lena.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(image_filename,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method in opencv to extract the **title** from an image. After we load the image in opencv by "imread", the image will be transformed into arrays/matrices. Its all numericals(***Christopher Nolan***) stuff :P .

One way I can suggest is, you can find **"contours"** by applying some heuristics like averaging/mean/medium of Area, width, height etc. and also try applying **"RLSA(Run Length Smoothing Algorithm)"** on those classified contours.

Documention and Code for [RLSA](https://pypi.org/project/pythonRLSA/) is [here](https://github.com/Vasistareddy/python-rlsa)